# LSP Jedi server error

Tags: python, lsp-mode

I've hit some trouble with `lsp-mode` and in particular `lsp-jedi`.

I have my virtualenv selected under Emacs using `pyvenv-workon` and `jedi-language-server` is installed under the virtual environment. At the command line it starts without error.

If I try opening a `.py` file in Emacs the server fails with...

```
INFO:pygls.server:Starting IO server
INFO:pygls.server:Shutting down the server
INFO:pygls.server:Closing the event loop.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 143, in deserialize_message
    deserialize_params(data, get_params_type)
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 129, in deserialize_params
    data['params'] = params_type(**params)
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 400, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InitializeParams
processId
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/bin/jedi-language-server", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jedi_language_server/cli.py", line 99, in cli
    SERVER.start_io()
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/server.py", line 178, in start_io
    self.loop.run_until_complete(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/server.py", line 68, in aio_readline
    proxy(b''.join(message))
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 464, in data_received
    json.loads(body.decode(self.CHARSET),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  File "/home/neil/.virtualenvs/python3_9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygls/protocol.py", line 145, in deserialize_message
    raise JsonRpcInvalidParams()
pygls.exceptions.JsonRpcInvalidParams: Invalid Params

Process jedi stderr finished
```

I tried running plain Emacs using the [lsp-start-plain.el](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/blob/master/scripts/lsp-start-plain.el) suggested in GitHub issues and can activate the virtualenv and open a file without any problem so I think there is some error in how Emacs/lsp-mode is calling/starting `jedi-language-server`.

My configuration for `lsp-mode` is...

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq lsp-idle-delay 0.5
        lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting t)
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :init (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l"
              lsp-bash-highlight-parsing-errors t)
  :hook ((python-mode . lsp)
         (bash-mode . lsp)
         (dockerfile-mode . lsp)
         (groovy-mode . lsp)
         (html-mode . lsp)
         (latex-mode . lsp)
         ;; (markdown-mode . lsp)
         (org-mode . lsp)
         (R-mode . lsp)
         (ess-r-mode . lsp)
         (sh-mode . lsp)
         (terraform-mode . lsp)))

(use-package lsp-ui
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-delay 1
        lsp-ui-doc-enable t
        lsp-ui-doc-header nil
        lsp-ui-doc-use-childframe t
        lsp-ui-doc-position 'top
        lsp-ui-doc-include-signature t
        lsp-ui-doc-use-childframe t
        lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil
        lsp-ui-flycheck-enable t
        lsp-ui-flycheck-list-position 'right
        lsp-ui-flycheck-live-reporting t
        lsp-ui-peek-enable t
        lsp-ui-peek-list-width 60
        lsp-ui-peek-peek-height 25
        lsp-ui-sideline-enable t
        lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover t
        lsp-ui-sideline-delay 3)
  :hook (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode)
  :bind (:map lsp-ui-mode-map
              ("C-c i" . lsp-ui-imenu)))

(use-package lsp-treemacs
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq lsp-treemacs-sync-mode 1))

(use-package lsp-jedi
  :ensure t
  :config
  (with-eval-after-load "lsp-mode"
    (add-to-list 'lsp-disabled-clients 'pyls)
    (add-to-list 'lsp-enabled-clients 'jedi)))
```

I tried `toggle-debug-on-error` to see what the problem was but couldn't get any info (presumably because the error occurs outside of Emacs with the way in which `jedi-language-server` is called).

Weird thing is I use the same configuration across computers, including a new work laptop where everything is fine.

Advice on how to go about working out what is going wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: looks like your version of pydantic is choking on something. try it in a new virtual env.

Comment: I thought that might be an issue so I reinstalled `pygls`and `pydantic`to no avail. I also used the exact same virtualenv with the `lsp-start-plain.el` that is suggested in the "issues" page on GitHub for `jedi-language-server`and there were no errors so I think I've eliminated that avenue.