# Can not configure lsp-enabled-clients via lsp-jedi

Tags: lsp-mode, jedi

I'm trying (again![1][2]) to get [`lsp-jedi`](https://github.com/fredcamps/lsp-jedi) working on one of my systems (Gentoo Linux, same configuration works ok under Arch Linux).

I have `pip install --user jedi-language-server` so that it is available under the user account without activating a virtual environment.

```bash
❱ which python
/usr/bin/python
❱ which jedi-language-server
/home/user/.local/bin/jedi-language-server
```

I modify my `exec-path` very early on in my configuration.

```
;; Modify exec-path
(setq exec-path (append '("~/bin"
                          "~/.local/bin"
                          "~/.cargo/bin/"
                          "~/.node/bin/"
                          )
                        exec-path))
```

If I `C-h v exec-path` includes `/home/user/.local/bin` and `M-: (executable-find "jedi-language-server")` it too returns `/home/user/.local/bin/jedi-language-server`, so things look good so far.

I have the following `lsp` and `lsp-jedi` (as well as `lsp-ui`) configuration....

```lisp
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :defer 1
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :config
  (setq lsp-idle-delay 0.5
    lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting t
    lsp-pylsp-plugins-pylint-args ["--rcfile=/home/neil/dotfiles/python/.pylintrc"])
  lsp-warn-no-matched-clients nil
  :hook ((lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
     (R-mode . lsp)
     (bash-mode . lsp)
     (dockerfile-mode . lsp)
     (ess-r-mode . lsp)
     (gfm-mode . lsp)
     (groovy-mode . lsp)
     (html-mode . lsp)
     (julia-mode . lsp)
     (latex-mode . lsp)
     (markdown-mode . lsp)
     (org-mode . lsp)
     (python-mode . lsp)
     (sh-mode . lsp)
     (terraform-mode . lsp)))

(use-package lsp-ui
  :ensure t
  :hook (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode)
  :config
  (setq
   lsp-ui-doc-border (face-foreground 'default)
   lsp-ui-doc-delay 1
   lsp-ui-doc-enable t
   lsp-ui-doc-include-signature t
   lsp-ui-doc-header nil
   lsp-ui-doc-include-signature t
   lsp-ui-doc-position 'top
   lsp-ui-doc-show-with-cursor t
   lsp-ui-doc-show-with-mouse t
   lsp-ui-doc-use-childframe t
   lsp-ui-doc-use-childframe t
   lsp-ui-flycheck-enable t
   lsp-ui-flycheck-list-position 'right
   lsp-ui-flycheck-live-reporting t
   lsp-ui-imenu-enable t
   lsp-ui-peek-enable t
   lsp-ui-peek-list-width 60
   lsp-ui-peek-peek-height 25
   lsp-ui-sideline-delay 3
   lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil
   lsp-ui-sideline-enable t
   lsp-ui-sideline-ignore-duplicate t
   lsp-ui-sideline-show-code-actions t
   lsp-ui-sideline-show-hover t)
  :bind (:map lsp-ui-mode-map
          ("C-c i" . lsp-ui-imenu)))

(use-package lsp-jedi
  :ensure t
  ;; :after lsp-mode
  :config
  (with-eval-after-load "python-mode"
    (add-to-list 'lsp-disabled-clients 'pyls)
    (add-to-list 'lsp-enabled-clients 'jedi-language-server)))
```

But when I look at `C-h v lsp-enabled-clients` it is reported as `nil` which is confusing.

Ok lets do the sensible thing and strip things back...

So I started with a plain Emacs session (`emacs -q`) and then loaded the above configuration and whilst `C-h v lsp-enabled-clients` now lists `jedi-language-server` as the `exec-path` includes `~/.local/bin/` the `jedi-language-server` binary is not found and its not even in the registered list...

```
lsp-enabled-clients is a variable defined in ‘lsp-mode.el’.

Its value is (jedi-language-server)

List of clients allowed to be used for projects.
When nil, all registered clients are considered candidates.
```

If I open a `*.py` file which triggers `python-mode` this doesn't change things, its still trying to find the default set of clients rather than `jedi-language-server`.

```
LSP :: Client semgrep-ls is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client ruff-lsp is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pyright is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pylsp is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pyls is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client jedi is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client semgrep-ls is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client ruff-lsp is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pyright is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pylsp is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pyls is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client jedi is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client semgrep-ls is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client ruff-lsp is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pyright is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pylsp is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client pyls is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: Client jedi is not in lsp-enabled-clients
LSP :: There are no language servers supporting current mode `python-mode' registered with `lsp-mode'.
This issue might be caused by:
1. The language you are trying to use does not have built-in support in `lsp-mode'. You must install the required support manually. Examples of this are `lsp-java' or `lsp-metals'.
2. The language server that you expect to run is not configured to run for major mode `python-mode'. You may check that by checking the `:major-modes' that are passed to `lsp-register-client'.
3. `lsp-mode' doesn't have any integration for the language behind `python-mode'. Refer to https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/languages and https://langserver.org/ .
4. You are over `tramp'. In this case follow https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/remote/.
5. You have disabled the `lsp-mode' clients for that file. (Check `lsp-enabled-clients' and `lsp-disabled-clients').
You can customize `lsp-warn-no-matched-clients' to disable this message.
```

The same happens if I activate a virtual environment first and I definitely have `jedi-language-server` installed in the virtual environment.

Completely baffled as the same configuration works fine on another system (albeit Arch rather than Gentoo but the system isn't the source of the problem here I don't think).

Any suggestions to try welcome and if I've omitted something please let me know.

Thanks,

slackline

[1]: [LSP Jedi server error I've hit some trouble with lsp-mode and in particular lsp-jedi. I have my virtualenv selected under Emacs using pyvenv-workon and jedi-language-server is installed under the virtual environment. At the command line it starts without error. If I try opening a .py file in Emacs the ...](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71760/lsp-jedi-server-error)

[2]: [lsp-jedi debugging](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72427/lsp-jedi-debugging)

**EDIT** : I think I may have made a mistake in my configuration as I've done some tinkering and after reading the [FAQ : I have multiple language servers registered for language FOO. Which one will be used when opening a project?](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/faq/#i-have-multiple-language-servers-registered-for-language-foo-which-one-will-be-used-when-opening-a-project) I checked `*lsp-log*` and it lists a found server (in a new virtual environment I had created) as `jedi` not `jedi-language-server`.

I've updated to

```lisp
(use-package lsp-jedi
  :ensure t
  :after lsp-mode
  :config
  (with-eval-after-load "python-mode"
    (add-to-list 'lsp-disabled-clients 'pyls)
    (add-to-list 'lsp-enabled-clients 'jedi)))
```

And still `lsp-mode` is not activated on opening a Python file which is recognised as such as has the major mode set to `python-mode` which sets `jedi` and disables `pyls` as language server which is great, but `lsp-mode` itself doesn't actually start, it errors with the following Backtrace which was too long to include in a post so its [pastebinned](https://pastebin.com/VBVnWKSW).

Answer (score 0):

Further tinkering and I think I've solved this, albeit by brute force and as usual the problem resided between the keyboard and the screen.

I had [python-lsp-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/) and [python-lsp-black](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-black/) installed globally under the system as well as having `pip install --user pylsp`.

After removing all of these `lsp-mode` can only find `jedi`/`jedi-language-server` that I have `pip install --user jedi-language-server` and also include as a default package to be installed whenever I create a new virtual environment.

As a consequence `lsp-mode` only find it as a possible client.

However, somewhat confusingly, if I start a new Emacs session and *don't* activate any virtual environment then I find that it uses an instance of `jedi-language-server` that is installed under a virtual environment...

```
Command "semgrep lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "ruff-lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "jedi-language-server" is present on the path.
Command "semgrep lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "ruff-lsp" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "jedi-language-server" is present on the path.
Found the following clients for /mnt/work/git/lab/nshephard/mvdate/mvdate/mvdate.py: (server-id jedi, priority -1)
The following clients were selected based on priority: (server-id jedi, priority -1)
```

Even though when I `M-: (executable-find "jedi-language-server")` it returns `~/.local/bin/jedi-language-server` which is the one installed with `pip install --user jedi-language-server`.

It's like the `exec-path` was completely ignored in favour of the priority settings which as far as I can tell can't be directly configured and its only via `lsp-enabled-clients`/`lsp-disabled-clients` that these can be configured (and even then they didn't seem to be recognised).

Somewhat confusing!

Further my `python-mode-map` bindings for doing tasks such as running `pytest` are no longer recognised!